# How to have two projects on git. one is based on another one and having sync done automatically in visual studio?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, bitbucket, git-fork

This may be a common problem among developers.
We have a base project which is acting as a platform for other projects.

let's say the base project is as follows:

**project-base**

file-base-1

file-base-2

file-base-3

the other project which is built upon the base-project should be as follows:

**project-module**

file-base-1

file-base-2

file-base-3

file-module-1

file-module-2

file-module-3

the problem with fork is that if we change **file-base-1** in the **project-module** and also we have some changes in the **project-base** on the same file we hit a merge conflict which should be manually resolved but that is not a proper way of doing things since we may have over 20 commits per day on common files.

in visual studio, you can consider **file-base-1** as a .sln file which tracks projects files. the **sln-base.sln** file has all the **project-base** settings and when we do a fork in to **project-module** the initial .sln file is the same as **sln-base.sln**

after that we may add some other files to the **project-module** so the sln file is updated. but this leads to the problem. renaming the .sln file also does not help since when we do a sync from master to the forked project the .sln file wants to be overwritten on the **sln-module.sln** ,so git asks us to do a manual conflict resolving procedure.

what is the best practice using git in scenarios like this?